# Sybase query: How can I sort the extraction (by well formed columns)

Tags: unix, output, sybase, columnheader

I built a *Sybase query* statement in a script (using the isql command/line ) below is the code:

My script contains:

```
isql -U databasename_dba -P password  <<EOF!
select  customerid, notional, counterparty2 from table_1  inner join  table_2
on id = id2 
go
quit
EOF!
```

I'm getting this:

[image: My output]

My **desired output** would be :

[image: Desired output]

Thinking that extracting just the data (excluding the headers)  might fix the output. I added in my code `-b`

```
isql -U databasename_dba -P password  -b <<EOF!
```

but the output doesn't change that much
[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you can pass in the -w parameter to give the width of the row so you don't get it overlapping across lines (e.g. -w2000)

The isql tool will return the column width dependent on the width of the actual table column so if for example you defined it as a numeric 18 but only use 12 digits you'll still get 18 characters in the output. You can use a `rtrim(customerid)` depending upon datatype or you can use `convert(varchar(12), customerid)`. I suspect someone may have defined it as 50 chars or more possibly. You can repeat this as required for each column.

You can also consider using sp_autoformat and see if this helps - http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36273.1570/html/sprocs/BABHCBIG.htm

Comment: sure, I used it and now it works. Appreciated your help.